# Not used laptop in 5 months, now the local system process takes 40% and my laptop becomes hot (loud fans)

Tags: laptop, temperature

I haven't used my laptop in roughly 5 months after I went away for a while.

For some reason, now my Win 8.1. laptop becomes somewhat slower. But the real issue is that the laptop now rapidly becomes hot and I think it's because
even when idling, the local system process takes roughly 40% of the processor power.

What could be the cause of this? Additionally, is there something the software of windows can do  to prevent this? E.g. some maintenance option?

EDIT: It takes 40% of processor power according to task host

Comment: "becomes hot" does not really describe a problem that can be solved.

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe it. Basically, the fan starts spanning a lot harder over a short time span (5 minutes?) which is something it didn't used to do. The air is also notably hot for a laptop that sits idly

Comment: So its a laptop, which you have not used in over 5 months, so did you remove the dust?

Comment: Could the dust account for the system processes taking a large portion of the available processing power as well? (I'll try to stick the vacuum cleaner in the air vents anyways first thing tomorrow morning). (Currently, running system maintenance and hope it helps)

Comment: "Could the dust account for the system processes taking a large portion of the available processing power as well?" - No;  Something else is going on.  You normally have to open the laptop, following the service manual, to make any real different in the amount of dust that exists on laptops.

Comment: The most probable reason (since you have not used the laptop) for this is build up of dust and dirt inside the laptop. Try cleaning up everything. Dust has strange effect on computing devices that you can never really explain well. From personal experience, I have had immense heat build up and funny behavior including improper graphics just due to dust.

Answer (score 2):

When a laptop is not used for quite some time, certain processes are not executed.

Windows has built-in maintenance features. They are scheduled to be executed periodically, but when the schedules are missed, somehow windows thinks it is a good idea to execute them the next moment it is available, and guess what, that is when you turn on your laptop.

A few of the things windows will do that can cause significant slow downs and CPU usage:

- Check, download and install Windows updates.
- Execute maintenance tasks (can be seen through the little flag in the system tray, hovering will say: Windows is doing routine maintenance)
- Microsoft Security Essentials (or Windows Defender) can update and scan your system.

Other programs that are not windows, can also do this, but the above 3 are quite likely to be happening for sure.

Best practice is to just run your laptop for 1 hour and let it sort out its problems, restart when asked, and then see if there are any remaining windows updates.

There are things you can disable to keep this from happening, but in essence that is reducing security and you should avoid doing that. So either use the laptop more often, or settle for a maintenance cycle every so often.